# DevOps Nuget Restore vs VisDev Nuget Restore

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, devops

I'm having trouble getting DevOps to build my project.  When I do a package restore is Visual Studio I get messages such as the following:

warning NU1701: Package 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.5' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.1'.

But doing a Nuget restore in DevOps... This is reports as an error and it doesn't restore or do the build.

Package Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.5 is not compatible with netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)

It feels like I'm missing a command option someone on the DevOps restore.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using the `PackageTargetFallback` feature of the csproj file.

```
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <Version>4.8.7</Version>
     
   <PackageTargetFallback>netstandard2.1;net472;net462</PackageTargetFallback>

      </PropertyGroup>
```

After adding this, nuget allowed packages from the specified frameworks to be restored.